# Строка нужного формата и содержит слово только один раз. Регулярное выражение

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Клиент может отправлять такие строки на вход.

ZZZ/USD:0.0001

или

USD/ZZZ:100000

короче это типа конвертера валют.

Я написал регулярное выражение под эту формулу

```
static String COEFFICIENT_PATTERN =
            "^[A-Z]{1,3}+/" + "[A-Z]{1,3}+=" + "[0-1\\u002E]{1,6}";
```

оно работает.

как дополнить его условием, что должки быть только одно слово USD?

USD/USD=1000 уже не верно

Comment: Не работает ваше выражение, у вас там знак `=`, а в примерах - `:`. `^[A-Z]{1,3}/[A-Z]{1,3}:[0-9.]{1,6}$` работает. Кстати, зачем точку так маскировать, `\u002E`? А точно `[0-1]` должно быть? Какие требования к этой (`[0-1\\u002E]{1,6}`) части шаблона?

Comment: спасибо = я что-то забыл поменять на : , точку я маскировал так как помню раньше сталкивался что на разных браузерах при вводе иногда не точка приходила. 0-1 да только числа, тут коэффициент отношения валюты к доллару минимальное 0.0001 и максимальное 100000

Comment: Но в вопросе  у вас `0.00001`, а не `0.0001`

Comment: это не суть. как дописать к существующему выражению проверку что usd встречается только один раз?

Comment: `"^(?!.*\\bUSD\\b.*\\bUSD\\b)[A-Z]{1,3}/" + "[A-Z]{1,3}=" + "[0-1\\u002E]{1,6}";`

Comment: здорово! я просто 2 регулярное написал которое отдельно бы проверяло а то что можно вставить в саму строку *\\bUSD\\b.* не догадался спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае, чтобы исключть совпадение целой строки, если какое-то одно слово в ней повторяется, можно использовать

```
static String COEFFICIENT_PATTERN =
    "^(?!.*\\bUSD\\b.*\\bUSD\\b)[A-Z]{1,3}/[A-Z]{1,3}:[0-1\\u002E]{1,6}$";
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/T8dxRd/1)

Или, так как повтор определённого слова тут может случиться только в начале строки один раз через `/`, в данном случае вы можете использовать

```
static String COEFFICIENT_PATTERN =
    "^(?!USD/USD:)[A-Z]{1,3}/[A-Z]{1,3}:[0-1\\u002E]{1,6}$";
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/T8dxRd/2)

Блок предварительного просмотра вперёд`(?!.*\\bUSD\\b.*\\bUSD\\b)` исключает совпадение, если сразу после текущей позиции (а тут эта позиция - начало строки) есть

- `.*` - 0+ символов, отличных от символов перевода строки, как можно больше
- `\bUSD\b` - целое слово `USD`
- `.*` - 0+ символов, отличных от символов перевода строки, как можно больше
- `\bUSD\b` - целое слово `USD`.